# Updating song details Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-contentresolver, mediastore

I've been developing a music library app and have come across an issue with updating song details.

Lets say, for example, I have an artist (Artist A) who has 2 albums (Album A & Album B).
When I change the album name value of a song from Album A to Album B it seems to create another album under the same name. This shows up on my app as Artist A having 3 albums (Album A, Album B, Album B).

What I'm hoping to achieve is that when I change the album name from A to B that the song is then recognized as being part of Album B. So that Artist A still only has 2 albums (Album A & Album B)

Here is my method for updating the songs details.

```
public void editSong(Song s)
{

   final Uri URI = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

   values.put(AudioColumns.TRACK, s.getTrackNo());
   values.put(AudioColumns.TITLE, s.getSongTitle());
   values.put(AudioColumns.ARTIST, s.getArtistName());
   values.put(AudioColumns.ALBUM, s.getAlbumName());

   String selection = AudioColumns._ID + "=?";
   String arg[] = {String.valueOf(s.getSongId())};

   ContentResolver.update(URI, values, selection, arg);

}
```

I have tried adding this, getting the albumID from elsewhere but no luck

```
values.put(AudioColumns.ALBUM_ID, albumID);
```

Thanks